# SQL/PHP - REPLACE statement not working as intended

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to 'remove' part of a string in a DB entry after a delete command is made.

Say a PDF file gets deleted, i want to remove the reference of it by replacing it with `''` (but keep the other references). That works fine, but now i also want to do it with another column, and the exact same setup doesn't seem to work and i can't figure out why.

This works:

```
$stmt_2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE data_videothek SET pdfAttachment = REPLACE(pdfAttachment, $id, '') WHERE pdfAttachment LIKE ?");
$stmt_2->execute(array( $like_id_string ));
```

This doesn't:

```
$stmt_2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE data_videothek SET speaker_img = REPLACE(speaker_img, $thefile, '' ) WHERE speaker_img LIKE ?");
$stmt_2->execute(array(  $like_filename_string ));
```

Both columns are defined as 'varchar' and all input in the query is as 'string'

I can't wrap my head around why the pdf one works, but the speaker_img doesn't.

The problem must be in `REPLACE(speaker_img, $thefile, '' )` because if i replace that with a simple `= ''`, the query performs fine and clears the whole cell if a match is made.

This is how i define the 2 input variables:

```
$thefile = (string)basename($row['filename'], ".png");
$like_filename_string = "%".$thefile."%";
```

For the curious why i save the info like that: There's only 1 field for the filenames, seperated by a "-", which when loaded gets 'exploded' into an array. It allows me to haven an open-ended number of attachments. Maybe not the best way of doing things?

Comment: "Maybe not the best way of doing things?" You are correct that is not the best way of doing things. You should normalize the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use parameters for `$id` and `$thefile` instead of variable interpolation, you won't need to worry about escaping chars, which is probably the reason the sql is malformed when you try to just use the value of `$thefile` inside a sql string.

Comment: Thank you Niloct - i feel dumb for not trying this, and it works. I was so hung up on why the first one worked and the second one didn't. Difference i guess being the first one only deals with numbers, while the other one with letters aswell. Anyway, seems to work now. Thanks a million